# Is there something wrong in this formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What’s wrong with this formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(C8:D8)=2,C8*D8,””)
```

I get `#NAME?` in the result cell. I’m using this formula to achieve a blank cell when D8 is blank. I think there must be something wrong with using the quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the quotation marks causing the problem. I copied Mael’s formula into the cell and it worked the way I wanted it to. They are the only quotation marks on my iPad keyboard so not sure how to get around that.

Comment: See if Excel is set to use smart quotes.

Comment: I’m using excel on an iPad. Can’t find where to check if it’s using smart quotes. There’s not much to change in Settings.

Comment: Sorry, can't be much help with that.  Maybe another reader who uses Excel on an iPad can provide some input.  It's possible that porting MS Office to such a radically different platform has some bugs or limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that D8 cannot be blank the way this is written. If D8 is blank the formula requires you multiply it by C8 - and since D8 isn't a number it doesn't know what to do with that. Without knowing much about your end goal or having Excel on the machine I'm answering from, it seems a formula like this may achieve your desired result:

```
=IF(D8="","",C8*D8)
```

or

```
IF(COUNTBLANK(D8)=0,C8*D8,"")
```

Comment: If D8 is blank, would the COUNT() really return 2?

Comment: I believe COUNT skips blank cells by default; based on the question it looks like they don't won't it to return 2 if it's blank.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with the formula is the character you're using for quote marks.  It isn't a quote mark (examine it with CODE to see the character code).  The formula will work as expected if you use actual quote marks.  Multiplying by a blank doesn't produce an error, the blank is treated as zero.  COUNT ignores blanks, so the COUNT expression results in FALSE, and Excel then doesn't know what to do with those symbols.

If that symbol is what's being produced from the keyboard, there is something else going on, like perhaps you have Excel set to use smart quotes and it is inserting two smart close quotes, or something similar.  Those use a high-order character as a placeholder that isn't treated as a normal character.

If you notice, the symbol in your formula is angled to the right.  Normal quote marks are vertical, as in the answer by mael'.  There's nothing wrong with the alternate formulas in that answer, but they will also fail if your keyboard is not producing quote marks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I managed to find where to turn off the smart quotes, it was in the iPad keyboard settings as "smart punctuation". All good now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `#NAME?` error because of the quotation sign `””` used with the Formula !!

Excel returns `#NAME?` error when fails to recognize any of the Reserve words(Function name/Operator) used in the Formula.

Therefore the first step should, correct the Command syntax (Command Patter) and your Formula should written like this,

`=IF(COUNT(C8:D8)=2,C8*D8,"")`

**N.B.**

- This Formula will Multiply `C8` with `D8` if & when `COUNT(C8:D8)` returns `2`. In case, if either of cells or both are blank, you get
  BLANK instead!!

Now considering the second part, **I’m using this formula to achieve a blank cell when `D8` is blank.**

So to test Cell `D8` is blank or not you may use this one,

`=IF(D8<>"",C8*D8,"")`

*Or the Formula shown by @mael' also.*

**Additionally**, if you want to Multiply `C8` with `D8` when the `Count is 2` by achieving none of the Cells (`C8, D8`) is blank, then you may use this one,

`=IF(OR(C8<>"",D8<>""),IF(COUNT(C8:D8)=2,C8*D8,""))`

**N.B.**

- If any of the cells (`C8, D8`) is blank then Formula return BLANK and if both are blank you get `FALSE`.

*Or this one can be used also.*

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C8:D8<>""))<>0,IF(COUNT(C8:D8)=2,C8*D8,""))
```